# Evaluate function stored in Matlab cell array

Tags: function, matlab, cell-array

I have a function called  `objective` in Matlab I evaluate by writing `[f, df] = objective(x, {@fun1, @fun2, ..., @funN})` in a script. The functions `fun1, fun2, ..., funN` have the format `[f, df] = funN(x)`.

Inside `objective` I want to, for each input in my cell array called `fun`, evaluate the given functions using the Matlab built-in function `feval` as:

```
function [f, df] = objective(x, fun)
f  = 0;
df = 0;
for i = 1:length(fun)
    fhandle   = fun(i);
    [fi, dfi] = feval(fhandle, x);
    f         = f + fi;
    df        = df + dfi;
end
end
```

I get the following error evaluating my `objective`.

```
Error using feval
Argument must contain a string or function_handle.
```

I do not get how to come around this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reference the elements of `fun` using curly braces

```
fhandle = fun{i};
```

PS
[It is better not to use `i` and `j` as variable names in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)

Alternatively, [a solution using `cellfun`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15224927/1714410).

Comment: Thanks!
But why not `i` and `j`?

Comment: @sehlstrom - see the linked question regarding `i` and `j`.

Answer (score 2):

A more elegant approach using [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html)

```
function [f df] = objective( x, fun )
[f, df] = cellfun( @(f) f(x), fun );
f = sum(f);
df = sum(df);
```

Note the kinky use of `cellfun` - the cellarray is the fun rather than the data ;-)